# merge 2 opencv images, then darken / lighten the main image

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, opencv, emgucv

i have 2 images. main image of a face, and a mouth image(a rectangle). i attach the mouth image to the main image replacing the main image's mouth. i'd like to make the mouth look like it belongs to the main image (colors around the mouth are too light/dark). 
i was wandering how to do so ? using mask functions ? or altering each pixel ?

main image and mouth image are both opencv images, but if bitmap class has a useful function for my problem i can change that type.

thanks in advanced.

Comment: Can you post actual test images?

Comment: Ideally you should try to post this in [Signal Processing](http://dsp.stackexchagne.com) community to find better answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an openCV function with a mask for the mouth area (cvAddS for instance). OpenCV probably has the best optimized implementation for this.   However if you really want the mouth to appear as part of the face you probably should use some sort of blending algorithm (I use Burt-Adelson spline image blending) and perhaps some histogram equalization.